# Error en ejecución de consulta SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hola amigos buenas tardes, estoy intentando ejecutar esa consulta en sql Oracle:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me arroja el siguiente error;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Curiosamente el error me lo está marcando en la linea 3 pero ya revisé y no parece error de sintaxis, o hay algo malo que estoy haciendo que no lo esté tomando en consideración? Espero y me puedan ayudar por favor.

Comment: Deberias poner to codigo como texto y no como foto

Comment: Si quitas el `;` del final, ¿funciona?. [Referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27987882/1545868) (en inglés).